# Problems with XUL Grid Layout

Tags: xul

I'm working on creating an XUL app right now and I'm stuck with a few problems at this point. My current file is here: http://projects.thecloudonline.net/gemxul/regrid.xul.

I want that second column to essentially "float: right" (like how CSS works on webpages). The red background shows me that part moved, but my content is stuck oriented left. How can I make the content go along with it?

Secondly, my overall goal is to get it so that the layout is essentially split in half. Setting maxwidth="50%" on the first column doesn't seem to do anything. Is that the correct approach, or am I way off there?

That's all for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
<grid style="border: #000000 solid 1px;">
    <columns>
        <column style="border-right: #666666 solid 1px;"/>
        <column flex="1"/>
        <column style="background-color:red;"/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <vbox>
                <label value="Launcher 1" id="l1_title"/>
                <button label="button" id="l1_btn" />
                <label value="This is a description for item 1." id="l1_desc"/>
            </vbox>
            <spacer/>
            <vbox>
                <label value="Launcher 2" id="l2_title"/>
                <button label="button" id="l2_btn"/>
                <label value="This is a description for item 2." id="l2_desc"/>
            </vbox>
        </row>
        <row style="border-top: #666666 solid 1px;">
            <vbox>
                <label value="Launcher 3" id="l3_title"/>
                <button label="button" id="l3_btn"/>
                <label value="This is a description for item 3." id="l3_desc"/>
            </vbox>
            <spacer/>
            <vbox>
                <label value="Launcher 4" id="l4_title"/>
                <button label="button" id="l4_btn"/>
                <label value="This is a description for item 4." id="l4_desc"/>
            </vbox>
        </row>
    </rows>
</grid>
```

There are several ways of doing this. Personally I wouldn't use grid for something like this. vbox and hbox in combination beats anything you would normally do in tables. But of course it depends entirely what your end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it did solve that issue. In case it matters, I'm basically trying to create a window (haven't decided if it will be maximized or not) that will launch certain things (webpages, really) depending on which button the user hits. I just figured a 2x2 grid would work the best.